# Failed to invoke successfully Error There was a problem with the eventhub Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed --while invoking in hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm getting this error when trying to invoke in Hyperledger-Fabric. 
Please find my code below.

```
var FabricClient = require('fabric-client');

var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
fabricClient.loadFromConfig(configFilePath);


var connection = fabricClient;
var tx_id = null;
var peers = connection.getPeersForOrg();
var event_hub = connection.getEventHub(peers[0].getName());

var channel = connection.getChannel();

connection.initCredentialStores().then(() => {
  return connection.getUserContext('admin', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
  if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
    console.log('Successfully loaded user1 from persistence');
    // member_user = user_from_store;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Failed to get user1.... run registerUser.js');
  }

  tx_id = connection.newTransactionID();
  console.log("Assigning transaction_id: ", tx_id._transaction_id);

  var request = {
    chaincodeId: 'mycc',
    fcn: 'createFruit',
    args: ['Fruit1', 'Banana2', '10', 'DineshDSV'],
    chainId: 'mychannel',
    txId: tx_id
  };
  // send the transaction proposal to the peers
  return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
}).then((results) => {
  var proposalResponses = results[0];
  var proposal = results[1];
  let isProposalGood = false;
  if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[0].response &&
    proposalResponses[0].response.status === 200) {
      isProposalGood = true;
      console.log('Transaction proposal was good');
    } else {
      console.error('Transaction proposal was bad');
    }
  if (isProposalGood) {
    console.log(util.format(
      'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s"',
      proposalResponses[0].response.status, proposalResponses[0].response.message));
    console.log(proposalResponses[0].response)
    // build up the request for the orderer to have the transaction committed
    var request = {
      proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
      proposal: proposal
    }
    var transaction_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID(); 
    //Get the transaction ID string to be used by the event processing
    var promises = [];

    var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(request);
    promises.push(sendPromise); 

    let txPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let handle = setTimeout(() => {
        event_hub.disconnect();
        resolve({event_status : 'TIMEOUT'}); 
        //we could use 
        reject(new Error('Trnasaction did not complete within 30 seconds'));
      }, 3000);
      event_hub.connect();
      event_hub.registerTxEvent(transaction_id_string, (tx, code) => {
        // this is the callback for transaction event status
        // first some clean up of event listener
        clearTimeout(handle);
        event_hub.unregisterTxEvent(transaction_id_string);
        event_hub.disconnect();

        // now let the application know what happened
        var return_status = {event_status : code, tx_id : transaction_id_string};
        if (code !== 'VALID') {
          console.error('The transaction was invalid, code = ' + code);
          resolve(return_status); // we could use reject(new Error('Problem with the tranaction, event status ::'+code));
        } else {
          console.log('The transaction has been committed on peer ' + event_hub._ep._endpoint.addr);
          resolve(return_status);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        //this is the callback if something goes wrong with the event registration or processing
        reject(new Error('There was a problem with the eventhub ::'+err));
      });
    });
    promises.push(txPromise);

    return Promise.all(promises);
  } else {
    console.error('Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...');
    throw new Error('Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...');
  }
}).then((results) => {
  console.log('Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed');
  // check the results in the order the promises were added to the promise all list
  if (results && results[0] && results[0].status === 'SUCCESS') {
    console.log('Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.');
  } else {
    console.error('Failed to order the transaction. Error code: ' + response.status);
  }

  if(results && results[1] && results[1].event_status === 'VALID') {
    console.log('Successfully committed the change to the ledger by the peer');
  } else {
    console.log('Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::'+results[1].event_status);
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error('Failed to invoke successfully :: ' + err);
});
```

I have tried using the CLI its working absolutely file. All the peers are running fine.
and the response Im getting in my console is:

```
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
Assigning transaction_id:  f64c079e92fd111bf71172f326e4d9db188ea3a38317152cdfbf24c6f65fbded
Transaction proposal was good
Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - ""
{ status: 200, message: '', payload: <Buffer > }
Failed to invoke successfully:: Error: There was a problem with the eventhub ::Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed
```

Please help me on how to rectify this error. 
Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Hi @dinesh dsv, 
Maybe try to elaborate a bit more on your question, by better describing the context (stack) and cleaning up your code to isolate the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider checking your config to see if you have the correct connection address and/or port.

Comment: https://github.com/dineshdsv3/Hyperledger-Fabric-supply-chain/blob/master/nodeApp/ConnectionProfile.yml - @TongShen..Here is the link to my configuration code. I believe everything is fine. Please tell me if there's an error in my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by changing the below line

```
console.log('The transaction has been committed on peer ' + event_hub._ep._endpoint.addr);
```

to

```
console.log('The transaction has been committed on peer ' + event_hub._endpoint.addr);
```

Its the change in version of fabric-client.